# French Proverbs

Tags: histoire

Salut!

Can you contribute a famous french proverb that you like most? (and maybe translate it as well?)

If this is a duplicate question, can you please guide me to a place where such an enumeration exists?

Je vous remercie!

Comment: You could find a list of proverb in the pink pages of a Larousse dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [question and answer site](/tour), not a discussion forum. Please [do not post “questions”](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) such as “what's your favorite …”: such questions don't have answers, only anecdotes.

Answer (score 2):

This [site](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/pays/france/) has a lot of proverbs, categorized and with explanations. Actually, way more proverbs than the average person knows. I like this one, absolutely not famous:

> Après rastel n'a métier fourche.

Answer (score 2):

A good classic one, also on the site Frank cited:

> [Nulle rose sans épine.](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/1294/nulle-rose-sans-epine/)

Comment: Very nice! I'm upvoting :-)